# How is Burnham's Mom able to find her?

Tags: star-trek, time-travel, star-trek-discovery

In *Star Trek: Discovery*, Burnham's Mom uses the Red Angel suit to escape a Klingon attack. She jumps around time but can never reach Burnham.

How then does she gain the ability to find Burnham in all these situations where her life is in danger, but couldn't jump back before the Klingon attack to save her?

Comment: Excellent point. I have two possible answers: 1) Plot hole = lazy writers 2) Time paradox (jumping back to save her, means there's no need to use the suit, which means she never went back and Burham gets attacked by the Klingons etc). Temporal mechanics gives me a headache! That said, I think it's point 1.

Comment: @Rebel-Scum - I think it's poor writing. Her mom saved her countless number of times in situations where she would have died, remember she warned Spock that Burham was in the forest and in danger? She came back in time to rescue Burham again when they created the trap for the Angel. I think it's writers dealing with time travel before the work out all the plot holes. Warning to future writers: DON'T USE TIME TRAVEL!

Comment: Who is she saving from the Klingons? Michael is clearly alive.

Comment: @BrianOrtiz - Her mom uses the Red Angel suit to jump back before the attack an attempt to rescue her. Problem is she jumps 950 years back in time.

Answer (score 1):

> How then does she gain the ability to find Burham in all these
>   situations where her life is in danger, but couldn't jump back before
>   the Klingon attack to save her?

Michael doesn't need saving from the Klingons. She had always survived the Klingon attack. So saving Michael isn't some "new" ability she gained.

As to how she saves Michael, all she has to do is travel back to a point after Michael died (from her perspective in the future), find out how and where she died from historical records, and travel back to that time to save her.

Comment: From the [script](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=star-trek-discovery-2017&episode=s02e11), her Mom says no matter how far back she travels, she never seems to stay permanently. How then does she manage to stay to rescue those people during the war and move them to another planet? Or stay long enough to rescue Micheal on the planet where they found Reno?

Comment: She jumped 950 years back in time, but all of a sudden can find Burham to rescue her on the planet or from dying? If you can jump all around time, why not rescue your husband? Or save Burham from being attacked? Yes, she survived, but still you can save her the trauma of thinking her parents died.

Comment: @nsonline Yes. She can't stay permanently. She can only stay temporarily. Long enough to save Michael or do whatever else. She's basically on a timer like Quantum Leap. Also, she jumped 950 years into the future, not the past.